# How to detect colorisation on a text box with Squish and Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, squish

I have a desktop application that has a form that people fill out in text boxes. If an invalid value is entered, then the box turns pink with a red border. I am using Robot framework with Squish to try and identify this error when it occurs on a certain textbox. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question is too general, without any specifics; that's not the idea of SO, it's not a tutorial or do-it-for-me site, but rather helping with an actual problem. For that it's expected from the submitter to show what effort has been put in so far, what has been tried. Consider going through the [mre] help section, and updating your question in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in QT, when actions happen they are firing signals and a slot in certain component. I'd assume that the state of the component is handled with something that triggers a signal that and the textbox receives it.

You could try to monitor what gets triggered when invalid input is given and use that in your asserts..

Another way, you might be able to read the property of your text input widget and see what changes when invalid input is given ..

Answer (score 0):

Getting the internal state that results in alteration of the rendering may not be straightforward, but at least depends on which GUI technology is in use. (You have not told us yet, I think.)

A simpler approach is to use a [screenshot verification point](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ug-vps.html#ugv-screen) (SVP) for just that control. In that SVP, you can use a positive mask to mark a specific area that is least likely to be affected by the contents of the control (to make the SVP as robust as possible).

A similar approach is to use (verifying the actual pixel colors used for rendering on the screen) [object.grabScreenshot()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.grabScreenshot-function) and use the API of the returned [Image Object](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#script-image-object) to query the color of an individual pixel via ***Image.getPixelRGB(x, y)*** and ***Image.getPixelRGBA(x, y)***.